# data.table print error when nrow>100

Tags: r, data.table

A strange error occurs when printing a data.table, but only when the data.table size is over 100 (example below). 
The error disappears when `print()` is replaced with `print.data.frame()`.
Hence, my guess is that `print`-->`print.data.frame` inheritance is recognized only when data.table size is no more than 100.

Can someone give an intuition why this happens?
My R version is 3.1.2.

```
library(data.table)

print(data.table(x=1:100), row.names=F) <-this command prints data.table

print(data.table(x=1:101), row.names=F) <- this command gives an error as below.

Error in `rownames<-`(`#tmp#`, value = rep.int("", nrow(x))) :
  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have your `datatable.print.nrows` option set to the default of 100.

```
getOption("datatable.print.nrows")
# [1] 100
```

You can change the number of printed rows by either changing the option's value or by using `nrows` in `print.data.table()`.  The latter is probably the best way to go as it will not change the default value.

```
args(data.table:::print.data.table)
# function (x, topn = getOption("datatable.print.topn"), 
#     nrows = getOption("datatable.print.nrows"), row.names = TRUE, ...)
```

This will work -

```
dt <- data.table(x = 1:101)
print(dt, nrows = nrow(dt), row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thx. the solution works for me. This is a bug in print.data.table function and can be fixed by replacing nrow(x) with nrow(toprint) in the line with 'else rownames(toprint) = rep.int("", nrow(x))'

Comment: @JKLim You are correct. It is an open bug: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1167