# data.table print error when nrow>100 for raw data type

Tags: r, data.table

This question appears closely related to: [data.table print error when nrow>100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32235244/data-table-print-error-when-nrow100)

The bug in that post has been fixed, as the comment says, but the 'raw' data type seems to generate something similar with `print()`:

> Error in rbindlist(l, use.names, fill, idcol) : Unsupported column type 'raw'

minimal example:

```
library(data.table)
x1 <- data.table(a=as.raw(1:101))
print(x1[1:100,])
print(x1[1:101,])
```

I just updated `data.table` but still does this.  Is it a bug?

The following works fine:

```
base::print.data.frame(x1)
```

`data.table` version 1.10.4-3

Comment: Interestingly, `print(x1, nrows = 101)` works.  I think the problem may have  more to do with `\`[.data.table\`` than `print()`.  Trying `x1[]` in the console also fails.

Comment: Pretty sure it's simply not a supported column type. You will run into errors at every step with a raw column, eg `x1[1:10, .SD, by=rep(1:2, each=5)]`