# Can data.table output be made to look more like tibble output? (10 rows, print only columns that fit screen)

Tags: r, data.table

Is it possible to change the settings in data.table so the default is to print only 10 rows and only the columns that fit the screen? Like a tibble df does.

I usually work on a laptop and would like to avoid the output in the example below.
Many thanks!

```
library(data.table)
dt_table <- as.data.table(mtcars)
dt_table
```

Output:

```
dt_table
     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear
 1: 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4
 2: 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4
 3: 22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4
 4: 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3
 5: 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3
 6: 18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3
 7: 14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3
 8: 24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4
 9: 22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4
10: 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4
11: 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4
12: 16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3
13: 17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3
14: 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3
15: 10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3
16: 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3
17: 14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3
18: 32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4
19: 30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4
20: 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4
21: 21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3
22: 15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3
23: 15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3
24: 13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3
25: 19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3
26: 27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4
27: 26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5
28: 30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5
29: 15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5
30: 19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5
31: 15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5
32: 21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4
```

**EDIT**:

I found a partial solution:

```
options(datatable.print.nrows=5,
        datatable.print.trunc.cols = T)
```

Which works for me. I anyone knows how to control how many n top / bottom rows separately? The option above will print 5 top / 5 bottom rows -- what if I want top 10, bottom 2? Is that possible?

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32235244/data-table-print-error-when-nrow100

Comment: Hmmm. No direct answer in that thread. I tried options(datatable.print.nrows=10), but that gives me 10 top + 10 bottom rows of df.

Comment: There is also `topn`

Comment: Check out my edit in the original post. Tried datatable.print.topn = 5 but it does the same as nrows?

Comment: There is a comment in that link about some bug.  Not sure if that is still active

Comment: There is also tidy option with `tidytable::as_tidytable(dt_table)` which does print similar to tibble and also maintains the data.table class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We may use `tidytable`

```
tidytable::as_tidytable(dt_table)
```

-output

```
# A tidytable: 32 × 11
     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
 2  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
 3  22.8     4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
 4  21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1
 5  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
 6  18.1     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1
 7  14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4
 8  24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2
 9  22.8     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2
10  19.2     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4
# … with 22 more rows
```

which would also keep the `data.table` class

```
> str(tidytable::as_tidytable(dt_table) )
Classes ‘tidytable’, ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 32 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ mpg : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
 $ cyl : num  6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
 $ disp: num  160 160 108 258 360 ...
 $ hp  : num  110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
 $ drat: num  3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
 $ wt  : num  2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
 $ qsec: num  16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
 $ vs  : num  0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
 $ am  : num  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ gear: num  4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
 $ carb: num  4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Answer (score 3):

Starting with:

```r
> nycflights13::flights
# A tibble: 336,776 x 19
    year month   day dep_time sched_dep_time dep_delay arr_time sched_arr_time arr_delay
   <int> <int> <int>    <int>          <int>     <dbl>    <int>          <int>     <dbl>
 1  2013     1     1      517            515         2      830            819        11
 2  2013     1     1      533            529         4      850            830        20
 3  2013     1     1      542            540         2      923            850        33
 4  2013     1     1      544            545        -1     1004           1022       -18
 5  2013     1     1      554            600        -6      812            837       -25
 6  2013     1     1      554            558        -4      740            728        12
 7  2013     1     1      555            600        -5      913            854        19
 8  2013     1     1      557            600        -3      709            723       -14
 9  2013     1     1      557            600        -3      838            846        -8
10  2013     1     1      558            600        -2      753            745         8
# ... with 336,766 more rows, and 10 more variables: carrier <chr>, flight <int>,
#   tailnum <chr>, origin <chr>, dest <chr>, air_time <dbl>, distance <dbl>, hour <dbl>,
#   minute <dbl>, time_hour <dttm>
> as.data.table(nycflights13::flights)
        year month day dep_time sched_dep_time dep_delay arr_time sched_arr_time
     1: 2013     1   1      517            515         2      830            819
     2: 2013     1   1      533            529         4      850            830
     3: 2013     1   1      542            540         2      923            850
     4: 2013     1   1      544            545        -1     1004           1022
     5: 2013     1   1      554            600        -6      812            837
    ---                                                                         
336772: 2013     9  30       NA           1455        NA       NA           1634
336773: 2013     9  30       NA           2200        NA       NA           2312
336774: 2013     9  30       NA           1210        NA       NA           1330
336775: 2013     9  30       NA           1159        NA       NA           1344
336776: 2013     9  30       NA            840        NA       NA           1020
        arr_delay carrier flight tailnum origin dest air_time distance hour minute
     1:        11      UA   1545  N14228    EWR  IAH      227     1400    5     15
     2:        20      UA   1714  N24211    LGA  IAH      227     1416    5     29
     3:        33      AA   1141  N619AA    JFK  MIA      160     1089    5     40
     4:       -18      B6    725  N804JB    JFK  BQN      183     1576    5     45
     5:       -25      DL    461  N668DN    LGA  ATL      116      762    6      0
    ---                                                                           
336772:        NA      9E   3393    <NA>    JFK  DCA       NA      213   14     55
336773:        NA      9E   3525    <NA>    LGA  SYR       NA      198   22      0
336774:        NA      MQ   3461  N535MQ    LGA  BNA       NA      764   12     10
336775:        NA      MQ   3572  N511MQ    LGA  CLE       NA      419   11     59
336776:        NA      MQ   3531  N839MQ    LGA  RDU       NA      431    8     40
                  time_hour
     1: 2013-01-01 05:00:00
     2: 2013-01-01 05:00:00
     3: 2013-01-01 05:00:00
     4: 2013-01-01 05:00:00
     5: 2013-01-01 06:00:00
    ---                    
336772: 2013-09-30 14:00:00
336773: 2013-09-30 22:00:00
336774: 2013-09-30 12:00:00
336775: 2013-09-30 11:00:00
336776: 2013-09-30 08:00:00
```

We can get most of the way there with:

```r
> print(as.data.table(nycflights13::flights), nrows=5, topn=5, class=TRUE, trunc.cols=TRUE)
         year month   day dep_time sched_dep_time dep_delay arr_time
        <int> <int> <int>    <int>          <int>     <num>    <int>
     1:  2013     1     1      517            515         2      830
     2:  2013     1     1      533            529         4      850
     3:  2013     1     1      542            540         2      923
     4:  2013     1     1      544            545        -1     1004
     5:  2013     1     1      554            600        -6      812
    ---                                                             
336772:  2013     9    30       NA           1455        NA       NA
336773:  2013     9    30       NA           2200        NA       NA
336774:  2013     9    30       NA           1210        NA       NA
336775:  2013     9    30       NA           1159        NA       NA
336776:  2013     9    30       NA            840        NA       NA
12 variables not shown: [sched_arr_time <int>, arr_delay <num>, carrier <char>, flight <int>, tailnum <char>, origin <char>, dest <char>, air_time <num>, distance <num>, hour <num>, ...]
```

I don't know of a way to *not* show the bottom so-many-rows. That aside, fortunately we can set those as options, either per-session (as below on the R repl prompt) or in a `.Rprofile` file for persistent use.

```r
options(datatable.print.nrows=5, datatable.print.topn=5, datatable.print.class=TRUE, datatable.print.trunc.cols=TRUE)
as.data.table(nycflights13::flights)
#          year month   day dep_time sched_dep_time dep_delay arr_time
#         <int> <int> <int>    <int>          <int>     <num>    <int>
#      1:  2013     1     1      517            515         2      830
#      2:  2013     1     1      533            529         4      850
#      3:  2013     1     1      542            540         2      923
#      4:  2013     1     1      544            545        -1     1004
#      5:  2013     1     1      554            600        -6      812
#     ---                                                             
# 336772:  2013     9    30       NA           1455        NA       NA
# 336773:  2013     9    30       NA           2200        NA       NA
# 336774:  2013     9    30       NA           1210        NA       NA
# 336775:  2013     9    30       NA           1159        NA       NA
# 336776:  2013     9    30       NA            840        NA       NA
# 12 variables not shown: [sched_arr_time <int>, arr_delay <num>, carrier <char>, flight <int>, tailnum <char>, origin <char>, dest <char>, air_time <num>, distance <num>, hour <num>, ...]
```

which is pretty close.

Comment: I will mark this as the answer. But if anyone knows how to set bottom rows separately, feel free to add!